# Saving a long set of vectors into just a row in "txt" file

Tags: python, list, vector

I have 10 by 10 vectors list to be saved into the txt file. However, when I open the file, every set of vectors is split into two rows. May I know if there is a possible way to make every set of vectors into just a row without changing the nature of the list? I have tried .join(), the set of vectors is indeed arranged into a row, but it's not a list anymore.

Here is my code for inputting the vectors into the 'txt' file:

```
def gradient_descent(df, ini_v, alpha, tolerance, MAX_ITER=300, output_fname='output.txt'):
    v = ini_v  
    with open(output_fname, 'w') as out:
        for i in range(MAX_ITER):
            gradient = norm(df(v), 2)
            v = v - alpha * gradient 
            msg = f'{gradient}, {str(v)}\n'
            out.write(msg)
```

and this is the text file after running the program:

```
10.435516278555651, [-0.04355163 -0.04355163 -0.04355163 -0.04355163 -0.04355163 -0.04355163
 -0.04355163 -0.04355163 -0.04355163 -0.04355163]
3.835516278555652, [-0.42710326 -0.42710326 -0.42710326 -0.42710326 -0.42710326 -0.42710326
 -0.42710326 -0.42710326 -0.42710326 -0.42710326]
1.4097227899779121, [-0.56807553 -0.56807553 -0.56807553 -0.56807553 -0.56807553 -0.56807553
 -0.56807553 -0.56807553 -0.56807553 -0.56807553]
0.5181358128224336, [-0.61988912 -0.61988912 -0.61988912 -0.61988912 -0.61988912 -0.61988912
 -0.61988912 -0.61988912 -0.61988912 -0.61988912]
0.19043795165812039, [-0.63893291 -0.63893291 -0.63893291 -0.63893291 -0.63893291 -0.63893291
 -0.63893291 -0.63893291 -0.63893291 -0.63893291]
0.06999441562278062, [-0.64593235 -0.64593235 -0.64593235 -0.64593235 -0.64593235 -0.64593235
 -0.64593235 -0.64593235 -0.64593235 -0.64593235]
0.02572606025068873, [-0.64850496 -0.64850496 -0.64850496 -0.64850496 -0.64850496 -0.64850496
 -0.64850496 -0.64850496 -0.64850496 -0.64850496]
0.009455471127708661, [-0.64945051 -0.64945051 -0.64945051 -0.64945051 -0.64945051 -0.64945051
 -0.64945051 -0.64945051 -0.64945051 -0.64945051]
0.003475306105004789, [-0.64979804 -0.64979804 -0.64979804 -0.64979804 -0.64979804 -0.64979804
 -0.64979804 -0.64979804 -0.64979804 -0.64979804]
0.0012773295333838193, [-0.64992577 -0.64992577 -0.64992577 -0.64992577 -0.64992577 -0.64992577
 -0.64992577 -0.64992577 -0.64992577 -0.64992577]
```

My desired output file is as below:

```
10.435516278555651, [-0.04355163 -0.04355163 -0.04355163 -0.04355163 -0.04355163 -0.04355163 -0.04355163 -0.04355163 -0.04355163 -0.04355163]
3.835516278555652, [-0.42710326 -0.42710326 -0.42710326 -0.42710326 -0.42710326 -0.42710326 -0.42710326 -0.42710326 -0.42710326 -0.42710326]
1.4097227899779121, [-0.56807553 -0.56807553 -0.56807553 -0.56807553 -0.56807553 -0.56807553 -0.56807553 -0.56807553 -0.56807553 -0.56807553]
0.5181358128224336, [-0.61988912 -0.61988912 -0.61988912 -0.61988912 -0.61988912 -0.61988912 -0.61988912 -0.61988912 -0.61988912 -0.61988912]
0.19043795165812039, [-0.63893291 -0.63893291 -0.63893291 -0.63893291 -0.63893291 -0.63893291 -0.63893291 -0.63893291 -0.63893291 -0.63893291]
0.06999441562278062, [-0.64593235 -0.64593235 -0.64593235 -0.64593235 -0.64593235 -0.64593235 -0.64593235 -0.64593235 -0.64593235 -0.64593235]
0.02572606025068873, [-0.64850496 -0.64850496 -0.64850496 -0.64850496 -0.64850496 -0.64850496 -0.64850496 -0.64850496 -0.64850496 -0.64850496]
0.009455471127708661, [-0.64945051 -0.64945051 -0.64945051 -0.64945051 -0.64945051 -0.64945051 -0.64945051 -0.64945051 -0.64945051 -0.64945051]
0.003475306105004789, [-0.64979804 -0.64979804 -0.64979804 -0.64979804 -0.64979804 -0.64979804 -0.64979804 -0.64979804 -0.64979804 -0.64979804]
0.0012773295333838193, [-0.64992577 -0.64992577 -0.64992577 -0.64992577 -0.64992577 -0.64992577 -0.64992577 -0.64992577 -0.64992577 -0.64992577]
```

Comment: try: `row = [gradient] + v` then `out.write(row)`.

Comment: Have tried, the txt file becomes more misaligned.

Comment: Oh, also use the python csv module to write it, use a `csv.writer` with `.writerow()`. method to write `row` above.

Comment: I've changed my code to this: `csv_writer = csv.writer(out)` with `for row in sequence: csv_writer.writerow([row])`. The result becomes everything in a column and the list disappears. Did I code it correctly?

Comment: get rid of the brackets `[]` around `row`, it should already be a list.

Comment: Oh, I see. probably should have realised this was with numpy data types. It's getting a little involved, I'll post an actual answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To write to file, it's a good idea to use the `csv` module. We'll have to convert the data back to native Python data structures to create the row to write. Note the use of `list()` below.

```py
def gradient_descent(df, ini_v, alpha, tolerance, MAX_ITER=300, output_fname='output.txt'):
    v = ini_v  
    with open(output_fname, 'w') as out:
        writer = csv.writer(out)
        for i in range(MAX_ITER):
            gradient = norm(df(v), 2)
            v = v - alpha * gradient 
            row = [gradient] + list(v)
            writer.writerow(row)
```

if you want to preserve the `[]` in the output instead of CSV-style output, you can do `str(list(v))`. instead of `str(v)` above.

Comment: Thank you so much! I guess this can actually work! I'm just curious if you get the ___enter___  error when you run it? Because I got myself that error.

Comment: @KevinChoonLiangYew My memory was a bit off, I thought the csv.writer was also implemented as a context manager, but you just do it with assignment. I've updated the code now.

Answer (score 0):

Following the answer from @bananafish, I have made some adjustments to my code:
This is the code by using CSV-style method:

```
def gradient_descent(df, ini_v, alpha, tolerance, MAX_ITER=300, output_fname='output.txt'):
    v = ini_v  
    with open(output_fname, 'w') as out:
       writer = csv.writer(out)
       for i in range(MAX_ITER):
            gradient = norm(df(v), 2)
            v = v - alpha * gradient 
            row = [gradient] + list(v)
            writer.writerow(row)
```

and here's the output:

```
10.435516278555651,-0.04355162785556521,-0.04355162785556521,-0.04355162785556521,-0.04355162785556521,-0.04355162785556521,-0.04355162785556521,-0.04355162785556521,-0.04355162785556521,-0.04355162785556521,-0.04355162785556521

3.835516278555652,-0.42710325571113045,-0.42710325571113045,-0.42710325571113045,-0.42710325571113045,-0.42710325571113045,-0.42710325571113045,-0.42710325571113045,-0.42710325571113045,-0.42710325571113045,-0.42710325571113045

1.4097227899779121,-0.5680755347089217,-0.5680755347089217,-0.5680755347089217,-0.5680755347089217,-0.5680755347089217,-0.5680755347089217,-0.5680755347089217,-0.5680755347089217,-0.5680755347089217,-0.5680755347089217

0.5181358128224336,-0.619889115991165,-0.619889115991165,-0.619889115991165,-0.619889115991165,-0.619889115991165,-0.619889115991165,-0.619889115991165,-0.619889115991165,-0.619889115991165,-0.619889115991165

0.19043795165812039,-0.638932911156977,-0.638932911156977,-0.638932911156977,-0.638932911156977,-0.638932911156977,-0.638932911156977,-0.638932911156977,-0.638932911156977,-0.638932911156977,-0.638932911156977

0.06999441562278062,-0.6459323527192551,-0.6459323527192551,-0.6459323527192551,-0.6459323527192551,-0.6459323527192551,-0.6459323527192551,-0.6459323527192551,-0.6459323527192551,-0.6459323527192551,-0.6459323527192551

0.02572606025068873,-0.648504958744324,-0.648504958744324,-0.648504958744324,-0.648504958744324,-0.648504958744324,-0.648504958744324,-0.648504958744324,-0.648504958744324,-0.648504958744324,-0.648504958744324

0.009455471127708661,-0.6494505058570949,-0.6494505058570949,-0.6494505058570949,-0.6494505058570949,-0.6494505058570949,-0.6494505058570949,-0.6494505058570949,-0.6494505058570949,-0.6494505058570949,-0.6494505058570949

0.003475306105004789,-0.6497980364675954,-0.6497980364675954,-0.6497980364675954,-0.6497980364675954,-0.6497980364675954,-0.6497980364675954,-0.6497980364675954,-0.6497980364675954,-0.6497980364675954,-0.6497980364675954

0.0012773295333838193,-0.6499257694209337,-0.6499257694209337,-0.6499257694209337,-0.6499257694209337,-0.6499257694209337,-0.6499257694209337,-0.6499257694209337,-0.6499257694209337,-0.6499257694209337,-0.6499257694209337
```

This is the part with the str(list(v)) method:

```
def gradient_descent(df, ini_v, alpha, tolerance, MAX_ITER=300, output_fname='output.txt'):
    v = ini_v  
    with open(output_fname, 'w') as out:
        for i in range(MAX_ITER):
            gradient = norm(df(v), 2)
            v = v - alpha * gradient 
            msg = f'{gradient}, {str(list(v))}\n'
            out.write(msg)
```

and I got this output:

```
10.435516278555651, [-0.04355162785556521, -0.04355162785556521, -0.04355162785556521, -0.04355162785556521, -0.04355162785556521, -0.04355162785556521, -0.04355162785556521, -0.04355162785556521, -0.04355162785556521, -0.04355162785556521]
3.835516278555652, [-0.42710325571113045, -0.42710325571113045, -0.42710325571113045, -0.42710325571113045, -0.42710325571113045, -0.42710325571113045, -0.42710325571113045, -0.42710325571113045, -0.42710325571113045, -0.42710325571113045]
1.4097227899779121, [-0.5680755347089217, -0.5680755347089217, -0.5680755347089217, -0.5680755347089217, -0.5680755347089217, -0.5680755347089217, -0.5680755347089217, -0.5680755347089217, -0.5680755347089217, -0.5680755347089217]
0.5181358128224336, [-0.619889115991165, -0.619889115991165, -0.619889115991165, -0.619889115991165, -0.619889115991165, -0.619889115991165, -0.619889115991165, -0.619889115991165, -0.619889115991165, -0.619889115991165]
0.19043795165812039, [-0.638932911156977, -0.638932911156977, -0.638932911156977, -0.638932911156977, -0.638932911156977, -0.638932911156977, -0.638932911156977, -0.638932911156977, -0.638932911156977, -0.638932911156977]
0.06999441562278062, [-0.6459323527192551, -0.6459323527192551, -0.6459323527192551, -0.6459323527192551, -0.6459323527192551, -0.6459323527192551, -0.6459323527192551, -0.6459323527192551, -0.6459323527192551, -0.6459323527192551]
0.02572606025068873, [-0.648504958744324, -0.648504958744324, -0.648504958744324, -0.648504958744324, -0.648504958744324, -0.648504958744324, -0.648504958744324, -0.648504958744324, -0.648504958744324, -0.648504958744324]
0.009455471127708661, [-0.6494505058570949, -0.6494505058570949, -0.6494505058570949, -0.6494505058570949, -0.6494505058570949, -0.6494505058570949, -0.6494505058570949, -0.6494505058570949, -0.6494505058570949, -0.6494505058570949]
0.003475306105004789, [-0.6497980364675954, -0.6497980364675954, -0.6497980364675954, -0.6497980364675954, -0.6497980364675954, -0.6497980364675954, -0.6497980364675954, -0.6497980364675954, -0.6497980364675954, -0.6497980364675954]
0.0012773295333838193, [-0.6499257694209337, -0.6499257694209337, -0.6499257694209337, -0.6499257694209337, -0.6499257694209337, -0.6499257694209337, -0.6499257694209337, -0.6499257694209337, -0.6499257694209337, -0.6499257694209337]
```